# How to store the players in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, storage

Pretty basic but I am creating a game and I will have 2 to 4 players in the game I need to know how I can ask the user how many players there will be then store this amount in my array for later us?!

this is what I wrote so far

```
    {
        int NumberofPlayers;
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter number of players (2-4): ");
                String StringNumberOfPlayers = Console.ReadLine();
                NumberofPlayers = int.Parse(StringNumberOfPlayers);

            }
            while (NumberofPlayers > 4 || NumberofPlayers < 2);
        }


        // need get the number of players and set the required elements in
        // playerPositions to 0 on the board
    }
            static int [] PlayerPositions = new int [4];

    static void Main()
    {
        ResetGame();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I see that you get the number of players, so what is stopping you from resetting the values in the PlayerPositions array ? Please post specific issues you are facing rather than asking posters write code for you.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track, just allocate the array with size of `NumberofPlayers`

```
static int [] PlayerPositions;

public void ResetGame()
{
    int NumberofPlayers;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number of players (2-4): ");
        String StringNumberOfPlayers = Console.ReadLine();
        NumberofPlayers = int.Parse(StringNumberOfPlayers);
    }
    while (NumberofPlayers > 4 || NumberofPlayers < 2);

    // need get the number of players and set the required elements in
    // playerPositions to 0 on the board
    PlayerPositions = new int [NumberofPlayers];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set size of array as NumberofPlayers.

```
PlayerPositions = new int [NumberofPlayers];
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, why don't you just create a list of PlayerPositions.

```
List<PlayerPositions> players = new List<PlayerPositions>();
```

Depending on the input from the user, add those many objects to the above list.

```
while (NumberOfPlayers > 0)
{
players.Add(new PlayerPositions());
NumberOfPlayers--;
}
```

Comment: For only up to 4 Players using a static array might be the best solution (depending on object complexity). As for your loop, I'd use a second variable, because otherwise you're losing the number of Players (unless you use the list length for that).

Comment: It's just an example. Ofcourse you would like to store the input from the user somewhere.